# Cloud run custom domain returning upstream request timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have the same service deployed on 2 different GCP projects. In one project, it's working correctly while the other project is not working. In advance, the only differences are the environment variables listed on the project level - mainly the IP addresses of our data repositories.

Focusing on the project where it's not working, I have the service fully online, and when I hit the default URL generated by Cloud Run  (https://xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-yyyyyyyy-uc.a.run.app), everything works perfectly. The /health endpoint created to test the data repositories connectivity returns a payload with *ALL GOOD* message, and no error is log printed, meaning everything is successfully running.

The problem occurs when I replace the default URL with any of our custom subdomains: prd-api.yyyyyy.com/health or api2.yyyyyy.com/health. All of these domains are mapped to the right service deployed more than 48hrs ago, the certificate seems to be issued, but the browser continuously hangs when I hit it. Only after long minutes of waiting returns::

> upstream request timeout

What do logs tell me?

- Once again, the default URL (https://xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-yyyyyyyy-uc.a.run.app) I get no issue:

> GET200 1.08 KB 15.7 s Chrome 96  https://xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-yyyyyyyy-uc.a.run.app/health

This means connections to all data repositories are successfully established.

- Compared with the custom domain, the log reports:

> MongoError: failed to connect to server [mongo_ip_address:27017] on first connect [Error [MongoError]: connection 5 to mongo_ip_address:27017 timed out

It's important to say this service has a static outbound IP address which is whitelisted to allow access to the database. Otherwise, this wouldn't work with the default domain.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your post, you are mapping to a specific URL path, `/health`.

As stated in the official documentation, [Map a custom domain using Cloud Run domain mapping](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains#run):

> You can map a domain, such as `example.com` or a subdomain, such as `subdomain.example.com`. You can only map a domain to `/`, not to a specific URL path like `/users`.

**EDIT:**

Problem was with cookies, clearing cookies on browser solved the issue.

Comment: I never mentioned I mapped the specific endpoint, I said I use those endpoints to test.

Comment: @Blackout you've mentioned that you have whitelisted a static outbound IP address, therefore you have configured your Cloud Run service's VPC egress to route all outbound traffic through a VPC network that has a Cloud NAT gateway, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: @Blackout that seems odd. Have you tried clearing your browser cache? or use a different browser?

Comment: Yes, we realized yesterday it was indeed a cookies issue. It even makes the case more intriguing, cookies middleware are taking action only after the initialization of the service (including establishing the connection to databases), but we were not passing this point...